# How do you call/use a storyboard located in a subproject

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift3, uistoryboard

I have added a subproject to my Xcode project and added it as a target dependency. I now want to use a view controller in a storyboard located in this subproject. I am wondering if this is possible and how you would instantiate the view controller from this subproject into your main project.

Calling

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Calculator", bundle: nil)
let calculatorViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "calculatorViewController") as! CalculatorViewController
self.present(calculatorViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

does not work since the "Calculator" storyboard is in the subproject. I am using swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that the `Calculator` storyboard is not in the main bundle.  That is where the runtime tries to look for it when you pass in `nil` for the bundle in the `UIStoryboard` initializer.

What might work is if you pass in the bundle for one of the classes that is contained in the Storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Calculator", bundle: Bundle(for: calculatorViewController.self))
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but the project doesn't find the CalculatorViewController.swift file. When you cmd-click it, it locates it just fine though. It's unresolved identifier

Comment: Have you added the sub project as a dependency of your main project?

Comment: Yes, is there an import statement I would be missing? I also added the Calculator.app as an embedded framework and included it in copy bundle resources

Comment: @SulaimanMajeed yes, you would need to import the module.  It would be something like `import Calculator`.